# Passing enum to a constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, enums

I have a base class `Shape` and some other derived classes like `Circle`, `Rectangle` and so on.

This is my base class

```
class Shape {

private:
enum Color {
    Red,
    Orange,
    Yellow,
    Green
};
protected:
int X;
int Y;

// etc...
};
```

This is one of my derived classes

```
class Rectangle : public Shape {
private:
int Base;
int Height;
string shapeName;

//etc...
};
```

This is how I call a constructor:

```
Rectangle R1(1, 3, 2, 15, "Rectangle 1");
```

My constructor:

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(int x, int y, int B, int H, const string &Name)
:Shape(x, y)
{
setBase(B);
setHeight(H);
setShapeName(Name);
}
```

I want to add one argument to my constructor so I can pass the color of the shape using `enum Color` in my base class. How can I do that? I also want to print the color as a `string`. I have no idea on how to use `enum` as an argument in a constructor.

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: i think you should not make enum Color private.

Comment: How is your current constructor look like ? Also I doubt you can achieve the goal, because `enum Shape::Color" is `private`.

Comment: @iammilind I've just added my constructor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, you should make Color protected or public. One simple way to make Color from enum to string is to use an array.

```
class Shape {
public:
    enum Color {
        Red = 0, // although it will also be 0 if you don't write this
        Orange, // this will be 1
        Yellow,
        Green
    };

};

class Rectangle : public Shape {
public:
    Rectangle(int x, int y, int B, int H, Color color);
};

string getColorName(Shape::Color color) {
    string colorName[] = {"Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green"};
    return colorName[color];
}

void test() {
    // now you may call like this:
    Rectangle r(1,2,3,4, Shape::Red);
    // get string like this:
    string colorStr = getColorName(Shape::Yellow);
}
```

Comment: Your `void test()` function is not clear for me. What I got from your answer is the way you passed `enum` `Shape::Red`. I didn't understand the way you created a pointer object. And I want `string colorStr = colorName[Shape::Yellow];` to receive any color, not only `Shape::Yellow`

Comment: @Jack in the Box You can use `string colorStr = colorName[Shape::Yellow];` to express all colors, like: `string colorStr = colorName[Shape::Red];` will give you `Red`.

Comment: Is it possible that I make a general one that can be used for all colors?

Comment: Changed answer. I'm not sure if this is what you need.

Comment: you'll always have to keep the string list in getColorName in sync with the enum. Because an enum is basically an int - you can only print it as a value. That's why you have to maintain a lookup table if you want to print is as something different than a number.

Answer (score 0):

The type name of an `enum` is its name, and *inside the class* the name is implicitly resolved to belong to the class.  In this case, a constructor argument like `Shape(Color color)` would define a base class constructor parameter named `color` that has your `enum Color` type.

Then your derived classes can call through to the base constructor, e.g. `Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height, const char* name, Color color): Shape(color) { ... }`.

Note that you must also change the visibility of the `enum`: a `private:` enumeration won't be available to subclasses so it must at least be in a `protected:` or `public:` section of the base class `Shape`.

As far as the `string`...please describe better what you intend to do.  For instance, are you trying to print the names of the colors or their numerical `enum` values?  If it's the former you might write a helper method like this:

```
void printColor (Color color, std::ostream& os)
{
    switch (color)
    {
    case Red:
        os << "Red";
        break;
    . . . // and so on
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the constructor will be look like when I create an object? How am I gonna pass the color? `Rectangle R1(1, 3, 2, 15, ???, "Rectangle 1");` What should I put in `???` ?

Comment: In code outside the class, the `enum` values are resolved by the class that they're in; e.g. `Shape::Red`, `Shape::Yellow`, ...